# Passing "long" value in http get params

Tags: java, rest, http, jax-rs

I use JAX-RS (Jersey) for handking http requests.

Everything works fine except when i excecute a http get trying to pass long values.

For example:

```
http://ip:port/MyRestHandler?Operation=Something&latitude=100.123456789&longtitude=13345.234566
```

When my server receives the request its automaticlly returns 400 code and its not even entering the getHandler.

Waybe its got to do with my params getting:

```
@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("latitude") long latitude,
@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("longtitude") long longtitude,
```

Any ideas on how to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`100.123456789` is not `long` value, its `double`
change your handler to receive `double`

```
@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("latitude") double latitude,
@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("longtitude") double longtitude,
```

Comment: Hi Dima, does it work to do a primitive "double" or is the object requried? "Double"

Comment: It has to do wiith that 10.1234 is not long. Long is a big integer. you are passing the wrong varuable type.